# Generating nested Numpy Arrays

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to write a function that will take as input a numpy array in the form:

```
a = [[0,0], [10,0], [10,10], [5,4]]
```

and return a numpy array b such that:

```
b = [[[0,0]], [[10,0]], [[10,10]], [[5,4]]]
```

For some reason I'm finding this surprisingly difficult.

The reason I'm doing this is that I have some contours generated using skimage that I'm attempting to use opencv2 on to calculate features ( area, perimeter etc...) but the opencv functions will only take arrays in the form of b as input, rather than a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is shape (4,2), `b` is (4,1,2)

```
a.reshape(4,1,2)
np.expanddims(a, 1)
a[:,None]
```

all work

---

```
In [503]: B
Out[503]: 
array([[[ 0,  0]],

       [[10,  0]],

       [[10, 10]],

       [[ 5,  4]]])
In [504]: B.tolist()
Out[504]: [[[0, 0]], [[10, 0]], [[10, 10]], [[5, 4]]]
```